# Missing hashtag with theme customizer header color

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

I'm trying to add a color to my theme for the `<h2>` tag on my website.
But now I've got the following problem:

The hashtag is missing before the color. So I get `000000` instead of `#000000`. It does show the color, I can change the color and it all works fine, until it is displayed on the site.

This is my code:

```
function cloudboxx_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    //All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_textcolor' , array(
        'default'     => "#000000",
        'transport'   => 'refresh',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_textcolor', array(
        'label'        => __( 'Header Color', 'cloudboxx' ),
        'section'    => 'colors',
    ) ) );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'cloudboxx_customize_register' );

function cloudboxx_customize_css()
{
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        h2 { color:<?php echo get_theme_mod('header_textcolor', "#000000"); ?>; }
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'cloudboxx_customize_css');
```

Output on site:

```
<style type="text/css">
    h2 { color:dd9933; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed it. When saving it to the database the hashtag is filtered out.
So with echoing the color, I just put a hashtag before it, like this:

```
function cloudboxx_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    //All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_textcolor' , array(
        'default'     => "#000000",
        'transport'   => 'refresh',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_textcolor', array(
        'label'        => __( 'Header Color', 'cloudboxx' ),
        'section'    => 'colors',
    ) ) );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'cloudboxx_customize_register' );

function cloudboxx_customize_css()
{
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        h2 { color: #<?php echo get_theme_mod('header_textcolor', "#000000"); ?>; }
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'cloudboxx_customize_css');
```